# Function argument as name of variable/array in R

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to create a vector with R but determine its name within the function call. In SAS I would use the macro language to perform a loop but with R, I can't find how to refer to a variable by name e.g. (Obviously this does not work but it describes what I'd like to do)

```
fun <- function(X, vectorName) {
    paste(vectorName) <- 1:X
}
```

I'd like to be able to call `fun(5, v)` and get a vector `v = c(1,2,3,4,5)` out the end.

Comment: I would have said that the function is already a part of the language, i.e you are reinventing `assign`, albeit with a reversal of the order of the arguments. I suppose that you would also want to use the "envir" argument if this is being done inside a function and you expected the variable to be available outside the function, say in the global environment. You _should_ present a complete use case when you pose such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is possible, it's not something you should do. A function should only have a return value, which you then can assign, e.g.:

```
v <- seq_len(5)
```

Or if you have to pass a variable name programmatically:

```
myname <- "w"
assign(myname, seq_len(5))
```

(Though I can't think of a reason why you'd need that.)